# Raise an exception in python3 for this method which check dictionary.get with default value?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, default

I have a requirement that I have to raise an exception in method "meth(a)", only way I can achieve is to declare dictionary "a" to some value such that a.get('v', 0) raise an exception

```python
def meth(a):
    if isinstance(a, dict):
        return a.get('v', 0)# I have to raise an exception from here
    return 0

a = {} #I have to give some value into this dictionary so that my meth(a) raises an exception'''
import re
import sys
import traceback

try:
    meth(a)
except Exception:
    print("meth exception!")
    sys.exit()
    raise
else:
    sys.stderr.write("meth has no exception")
```

Comment: First, your code isn't indented properly which makes it very hard to read... Second, `dict.get` with when passed a string won't raise an exception.  As it is, this question is very unclear.  Why do you want to raise an exception?  Which exception do you want to raise?

Comment: Please fix your indentation - hard to understand. `dict.get(key, default_value)` doesn't raise an exception - just use `return a['v']` which will raise a `KeyError` if the `'v'` doesn't exist as a key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ya, I do know that dict.get(key, default_value) doesn't raise any exception but this question has been asked in a seminar since then I am wondering how this can be achieved. I am allowed only to change dictionary "a".

Comment: Do you mean "change dictionary a" (doable) or "give some value into this dictionary" (not doable). Those are very different! In the first case, define your own class that inherits from `dict` and implements a `get` that raises an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by *declare dictionary "a" to some value*. You can create your own class that inherits from `dict` so that the `isinstance` test works and implement an unfriendly `get`.

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def get(self, name, default=None):
        raise NameError("No way am I getting you a value. "
            "What kind of a dict do you think I am?")

a = MyDict()
```

and the rest is just your program...